# It is not important who he is

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

**It is not important who he is. = Who he is is not important.** 
Is that right??
That structure 'is' is said twice seem strange to me.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. You need two 'is'es here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

Regarding the double *is*:

- the first *is* applies to *he*
- he second *is* applies to *who he is* or his identity

You could replace *who he is* in this way if it helps you parse the sentence:

> His identity is not important

Grammatically, *who he is* is the subject of the sentence, and the second *is* is the verb of the sentence.